# Dual display through X11 protocol

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, x11-forwarding

I have a question: I'm working on a computer that has no secondary display output, but another computer in the network has one.
Is this possible to extend the second monitor through X11 with the computer which hasn't a secondary display ?

CA: computer which has only one VGA output
CB: computer which has VGA/DVI outputs 
MA: monitor of the CA and CB (using a device which could switch the source computer)
MB: monitor for extended desktop

CA -> MA
CB -> MA+MB (extended desktop)

Both CA and CB are on Linux (X11)

All I want to know if this is possible to do

CA -> MA+MB (through X11)
CB -> MA+MB (normal extended desktop feature)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I use `Xephyr` for this, which you will have to download from the repos.

On the screen of the machine where you want the display, issue the command:

```
   Xephyr -ac :7  -screen widthxheight
```

(remember the `x` between width and height). The option `ac` abolishes further controls, the `:7` instructs Xephyr to use the display #7. You 
can do this even from an ssh session, see the command `wmctrl` to learn how to move your window to the display you wish to use.

On the machine which has no screen, use:

```
     xhost +IP.Address.Of.The.Other.Machine:7
     export DISPLAY=IP.Address.Of.The.Other.Machine:7
     startkde
```

or start whichever graphical session or application you like.

All of this is rather insecure, both because of the use of `xhost` and because of the use of un-encrypted communication channel. At home it might be ok, at work or at school it could be dangerous, on public AP it should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: It's not exactly what he wants here. This solution will not allow an "extended desktop" on two monitors I think. However, I heard of Xdmx which I think is exactly what he wants: use 2 screens connected to different computers on a single X server enabling extended desktop with Xinerama. I've never tried it though.